# He would/was going to invent a device named iPhone. - in telling a past thing

Tags: tense, usage, modal-verbs

**Version 1**

> As he stared at the little gadget, he could see the future rolling out in front of him. He **would** invent a device named iPhone.

**Version 2**

> As he stared at the little gadget, he could see the future rolling out in front of him.
> He **was going to** invent a device named iPhone.

Are both versions mean the same here?

I know "was going to" usually implies the thing did not actualy get to happen. However, I don't know if it can be used the same way as "would" when in telling a past story.

Comment: **Was going to** sometimes means that the thing didn't happen - "We were going to go for a walk, but it started to rain" - but not always. Here, it would mean "he planned to...".

Comment: Nobody 'invented' the iPhone or Android phones (like mine!) for that matter.

Comment: In your context, ***would*** and ***was going to*** mean the same, and are interchangeable (it's a stylistic choice). In other contexts, such as if he'd *intended* to invent the iPhone, but failed to achieve that goal, ***was going to*** can carry that sense as it stands, but version #1 would need to be changed to *He **would have invented** a device named iPhone [**but** he couldn't raise the financial backing he needed]*.

Answer (score 0):

They mean the same thing, although to me, **would** implies that it's in the more distant future and **was going to** implies that it would happen sooner.

I'm not sure **invent** is the right word to use when talking about the iPhone, however. But that wasn't part of your question.